# google glass voice command conflict?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I'm still waiting for my Google Glass, but I have a question about how Glass voice commands work.conflicts will be handled? For example, how will "ok glass play a game" be handled? Do you have to reserve certain commands or user will be presented with apps using it to choose from?

Answer (score 0):

You will be "limited" to certain commands, but the team is open to allowing for new commands as long as they are generic enough and meet some broad criteria for use. During the developer preview, you're able to add your own commands, but you should be mindful of what you'll need to be working with in the future.

In the event there is a conflict between the commands, another screen will come up after the voice command prompting you which target you want to use to complete the voice command. You can see this a bit today when you use the "Post an update to..." command how it will prompt you who you want to use to handle the command.

Answer (score 0):

Google Glass has a special process to request recognition of particular voice commands ... "play a game" may not be one of the accepted ones .. we will have to see. [See here for commands](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/input/voice?hl=en#existing_voice_commands) to use or for a way to submit a New command for inclusion.